# Memory error when repairing malformed xml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, elementtree, large-files

I have some malformed XML that is very large--it lacks a top-level tag and there are duplicate attributes. To get around this, I tested the following solution on a subset of my malformed XML and it works perfectly to add a tag and automatically drop duplicate attributes using `BeautifulSoup`.

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

flow_file = sys.stdin.read()

try:
    tree = ET.fromstring(flow_file)
    sys.stdout.write(flow_file)
except:
    flow_file = f"<dispatch>{flow_file}</dispatch>"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(flow_file, 'xml')
    sys.stdout.write(soup)
```

However, since my real file is so large it throws a memory error. Since I need (AFAICT) the full XML to add top-level tags and drop duplicates, I'm not quite sure how to modify my code to handle such large XML. I saw some suggestions for using `lxml` and iterating, but I'm not clear on how it fits into my needs/processes.

ETA: not sure if helpful, but the whole point of this is to clean up the file so that it can run through NiFi's `SplitXML` processor.

Comment: If it is a file, could you try to not read it in all at once, but use ElementTree's iterparse instead? I once parsed a several GB file with this approach. ```for event, elem in etree.iterparse("big.xml", events=('start', 'end')):``` then work with the content and in the end ```if event == "end": root.clear()``` to clear memory. I will post a more detailed answer, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @n00by0815 That looks exactly like what I need, but will I be able to use BeautifulSoup how I need? (to drop duplicate attributes)

Comment: I don't really see in your post, what you do with the data. What I did, was find the open tag of an element, take up all of the contents within that element, process it, as I need (in your case, maybe write to an output xml) and clear the root, so my ram does not run full. I'll post a bit of code as an answer and you can see for yourself, if that is usable.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't really know, what you do with the data, here is the approach I took on a several GB big xml file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

root = False
#iterparse file, get event tags start and end
for event, elem in etree.iterparse("my_big.xml", events=('start', 'end')):
#set first element as rootelement, so we can clear it later
    if event == "start" and root == "False":
        root = elem
#Here we look for a certain end tag
    if event == "end" and elem.tag == "TAGOFINTEREST":
#set found False, so we can break, as soon, as we found our DataOfInterest
        found = False
#iterate through children and iterate over child nodes
#HERE I guess you would work with pandas
        for stuff in elem.getchildren():
#if found == True stop iterating or whatever condition you have
            if found:
                break
             #look for what you need, set found to True and break the 
             found = True
#clear elem, in order to save RAM
        elem.clear()

#Might require revision clears RAM after every "end" event
    if event == "end":
        root.clear()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great, however, it fails because the XML is malformed--thus why I'm trying to parse using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Catching the exception with a ```try: do_something() except: do_something_else()``` doesn't work either? if it fails with a certain error message, please update your post as well, as it makes it easier to troubleshoot. Or post some sample xml.